# What is the proper way to wrap isInstanceOf[] calls?

Tags: scala, reflection, dynamic-cast

I'd like to build a wrapper for `isInstanceOf[T]` and `asInstanceOf[T]` pair that would output `Option[T]` with convenient `map` and `getOrElse` methods.

So I give a try, but the result has disappointed me.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.{TypeTag, typeOf}

class Base()
class Deep() extends Base
class Deeper() extends Deep()

final case class WrapSimple[T](source : T) {
  def cast[U] : Option[U] =
    if (source.isInstanceOf[U]) Some(source.asInstanceOf[U]) else None
}

final case class WrapFullTagged[T: TypeTag](source : T) {
  def cast[U : TypeTag] : Option[U] =
    if (typeOf[T] <:< typeOf[U]) Some(source.asInstanceOf[U]) else None
}

final case class WrapHalfTagged[T](source : T) {
  val stpe = {
    val clazz = source.getClass
    val mirror = scala.reflect.runtime.universe.runtimeMirror(clazz.getClassLoader)
    mirror.classSymbol(clazz).toType
  }
  def cast[U : TypeTag] : Option[U] =
    if (stpe <:< typeOf[U]) Some(source.asInstanceOf[U]) else None
}

object Test {
  val base = new Base
  val deep = new Deep
  val deeper = new Deeper
  val wile : Deep = new Deeper

  def testSimple() : Unit = {
    println(WrapSimple(deep).cast[Base].isDefined) // should be true
    println(WrapSimple(deep).cast[Deeper].isDefined) // should be false
    println(WrapSimple(wile).cast[Deeper].isDefined) // should be true
  }

  def testFullTagged() : Unit = {
    println(WrapFullTagged(deep).cast[Base].isDefined) // should be true
    println(WrapFullTagged(deep).cast[Deeper].isDefined) // should be false
    println(WrapFullTagged(wile).cast[Deeper].isDefined) // should be true
  }

  def testHalfTagged() : Unit = {
    println(WrapHalfTagged(deep).cast[Base].isDefined) // should be true
    println(WrapHalfTagged(deep).cast[Deeper].isDefined) // should be false
    println(WrapHalfTagged(wile).cast[Deeper].isDefined) // should be true
  }

  def testAll() : Unit = {
    testSimple()
    testFullTagged()
    testHalfTagged()
  }
}
```

`WrapSimple` looks good, but just does not work, it erases the `U` type in the `isInstanceOf[U]` method application, so it is always responds with `true`. The funny thing is that `asInstanceOf[U]` keeps the `U` type normally, so it just produces runtime exceptions.

The second approach I had tried is `WrapFullTagged` that employs type tags. It seems clear enough, but again plainly breaks the contract. It could only check static types at compile time and has zero insight about actual types in runtime.

So, I breed both approaches and gave birth to the third, that at least produces correct output. But it looks awful and invokes power of reflection that comes with a great cost.

Is it possible to solve the issue with greater elegance?

Comment: You'll never get much insight about types at run time, because they are erased. The only way you can have _all_ of the type information at run time is if you preserve it at compile time via `TypeTag`s. In the first example both `T` and `U` are erased. Can you name a use case where `WrapFullTagged` doesn't provide the result you want?

Comment: Every time you would like to use `isInstanceOf`. That happens when you are unaware of actual type behind the runtime variable. It occurs quite often. You can try to remember when you wrote a project without any pattern matching last time.

Comment: shapeless typeable https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/typeable.scala

Comment: macro substitution may be implemented much easier, but it may be a good path to take

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out `scala.reflect.ClassTag`. It provides access to the erased class Type, and [according to the api docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.reflect.ClassTag) for the function with type

```
def unapply(x: Any): Option[T]
```

> A ClassTag[T] can serve as an extractor that matches only objects of type T.

An example that matches the expected output in the question and appears reasonably elegant:

```
class Base()
class Deep() extends Base
class Deeper() extends Deep()

case object SimpleCaster {
  def cast[A](t: Any)(implicit classTag: scala.reflect.ClassTag[A]): Option[A] = classTag.unapply(t)
}

object Test {
  val base = new Base
  val deep = new Deep
  val deeper = new Deeper
  val wile: Deep = new Deeper

  def testSimple(): Unit = {
    val a = SimpleCaster.cast[Base](deep)
    val b = SimpleCaster.cast[Deeper](deep)
    val c = SimpleCaster.cast[Deeper](wile)
    println(s"${a.isDefined} - ${a.map(_.getClass)}")
    println(s"${b.isDefined} - ${b.map(_.getClass)}")
    println(s"${c.isDefined} - ${c.map(_.getClass)}")
  }
}
```

results in the console output:

```
scala> Test.testSimple
true - Some(class Deep)
false - None
true - Some(class Deeper)
```

In summary; whilst this uses the reflect apis, it looks a practical solution that isn't too verbose.